# Jquery animate back when click other div not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

here is the demo link  - http://codepen.io/malithmcr/pen/CpDnB/

i have two or more divs on left side and  4 divs on right side, and i need to animate right side div's when i click left1 class, and then i need to animate back right side div's when i click left2 class..

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".left1").click(function(){
             $('.right01').stop().animate({'margin-left': '10px'}, 600);
             $('.right02').stop().animate({'margin-left': '200px'}, 1000);
             $('.right03').stop().animate({'margin-left': '300px'}, 1200);
             $('.right04').stop().animate({'margin-left': '50px'}, 300);
       }, function(){
             $('.right01').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 200);
             $('.right02').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 400);
             $('.right03').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 500);
             $('.right04').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 800);
       });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left1">Left one</div>
<div class="left2">Left one</div>
<div class="right01">right one</div>
<div class="right02">right 2</div>
<div class="right03">right 3</div>
<div class="right04">right 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.right01{float:left;margin-left:100%;}
.right02{float:left;margin-left:100%;}
.right03{float:left;margin-left:100%;}
.right04{float:left;margin-left:100%;}
```

thank you

Comment: You can't pass two functions to .click() like you can with .hover().

Comment: thanks, how can i do this ? anyidea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach two click events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".left1").click(function(){
        $('.right01').stop().animate({'margin-left': '10px'}, 600);
        $('.right02').stop().animate({'margin-left': '200px'}, 1000);
        $('.right03').stop().animate({'margin-left': '300px'}, 1200);
        $('.right04').stop().animate({'margin-left': '50px'}, 300);
   });
    $(".left2").click(function(){
       $('.right01').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 200);
        $('.right02').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 400);
        $('.right03').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 500);
        $('.right04').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100%'}, 800);
    });
});
```

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K9H6q/)